# Yii2 and postgres connecttion

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I tried yii2 and postgres database but when I try to query my table i got an error . How to fix this?

LINK for my error:
[image: Screenshot]

---

LINK for my database connection:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You don't have **tbl_user** in database?!!

Comment: Have you created model called `tbl_user`? Or is it your table name? If this is model than it's not there and that is why you've got error. If this should be table name go back to the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) and read about ActiveRecord.

Comment: Yes sir tbl_user is my table name. thank you sir @Bizley now its work, i created a model same name with my table.

Answer (score 4):

maybe you don't set **defaultSchema** on connection string

```
    return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name', 
    'username' => 'db_username',
    'password' => 'db_password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'schemaMap' => [
      'pgsql'=> [
        'class'=>'yii\db\pgsql\Schema',
        'defaultSchema' => 'public' //specify your schema here
      ]
    ], // PostgreSQL
];
```

[see to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436024/how-to-set-default-schema-in-yii2)

OR 
change your `tableName()` function in model like this

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'schemaName.table_name';
}
```